# Best Solution for this array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using checkboxes to query the database and I am struggling with this one, I am new to MySQL and PHP so sorry if this is simple!

Here is my code that I have...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="season2005" value="2005" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2005'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2005-06
<input type="checkbox" name="season2006" value="2006" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2006'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2006-07
<input type="checkbox" name="season2007" value="2007" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2007'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2007-08
<input type="checkbox" name="season2008" value="2008" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2008'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2008-09
<input type="checkbox" name="season2009" value="2009" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2009'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2009-10
<input type="checkbox" name="season2010" value="2010" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2010'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2010-11
<input type="checkbox" name="season2011" value="2011" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2011'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2011-12
<input type="checkbox" name="season2012" value="2012" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2012'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2012-13
<input type="checkbox" name="season2013" value="2013" <?php if(isset($_POST['season2013'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> > 2013-14

if (@$_POST['season2005'] == ""){ $season2005 = "0000"; } else { $season2005 = "2005"; }
if (@$_POST['season2006'] == ""){ $season2006 = "0000"; } else { $season2006 = "2006"; }
if (@$_POST['season2007'] == ""){ $season2007 = "0000"; } else { $season2007 = "2007"; }
if (@$_POST['season2008'] == ""){ $season2008 = "0000"; } else { $season2008 = "2008"; }
if (@$_POST['season2009'] == ""){ $season2009 = "0000"; } else { $season2009 = "2009"; }
if (@$_POST['season2010'] == ""){ $season2010 = "0000"; } else { $season2010 = "2010"; }
if (@$_POST['season2011'] == ""){ $season2011 = "0000"; } else { $season2011 = "2011"; }
if (@$_POST['season2012'] == ""){ $season2012 = "0000"; } else { $season2012 = "2012"; }
if (@$_POST['season2013'] == ""){ $season2013 = "0000"; } else { $season2013 = "2013"; }

$seasons = array($season2005,$season2006,$season2007,$season2008,$season2009,$season2010,$season2011,$season2012,$season2013);
$seasonpick = implode(",",$seasons);;

$matcharrays = array("AND season in ($seasonpick)");
```

At the moment all of the data is being queried to the database, so if nothing is selected them then part of query from this is "AND season in (0000,0000,0000,0000) etc

How would I go about only getting those selected into the array and if none are selected then the array would be blank.

Hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: Name every checkbox the same and add brackets `[]` like this: `name="checkbox[]"` this will return an array which you can loop.

Comment: As Daan said, if you group the checkboxes together by using `name=season[]`, when you submit the form the `season[]` will be passed as on array that you can iterate over to obtain the checkbox values you require. I see that you are using some conditional checks so that when the form reloads some checkboxes are already checked - with the array we're suggesting you will need to create a loop on your form page and you can check each value according to the array value to "pre" check your boxes as you did previously...

Comment: Whats with the error message suppression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working form with some checkboxes that will allow you to test and get the sql you intended.

```
<?php

    $dateArr=array();
    if(isset($_POST['season']))
    {
        $dateArr=array_unique($_POST['season']);
        $dateSearch=implode(",", $dateArr);
        $sql=".... and season in (".$dateSearch.")";
        echo $sql;
    }


?>

<html>
<form action="?" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"season[]\" value=\"".($i+2005)."\"> ".($i+2005);
    }
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Output when 2009, 2010 and 2011 selected:

> .... and season in (2009,2010,2011)

Okay, so how it works:

Checkboxes are best used when they all have the same name ending in a `[]`. This makes it a nice array on it's own.

If post data is set, we then quickly throw an array unique over it (good habit for the most part in these types of queries) so that there are no duplicate values.

Then simply implode it into a string and pop it into the SQL query.

Edit: Added functionality to re-check checkboxes when submitted.

```
<?php

    $dateArr=array();
    if(isset($_POST['season']))
    {
    $dateArr=array_unique($_POST['season']);
    $dateSearch=implode(",", $dateArr);
    $sql=".... and season in (".$dateSearch.")";
    echo $sql;
    }


?>

<html>
<form action="?" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
    $chk="";
    if(!empty($_POST['season']))
    {
        if(in_array($i+2005, $_POST['season']))
        {
            $chk=" checked=\"checked\" ";
        }
    }
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"season[]\" ".$chk." value=\"".($i+2005)."\"> ".($i+2005);
    }
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Edit 2: Just add quotes in the right places :)

```
<?php

    $dateArr=array();
    if(isset($_POST['season']))
    {
    $dateArr=array_unique($_POST['season']);
    $dateSearch=implode("', '", $dateArr);
    $sql=".... and season in ('".$dateSearch."')";
    echo $sql;
    }


?>

<html>
<form action="?" method="post">
<?php
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
    $chk="";
    if(!empty($_POST['season']))
    {
        if(in_array(($i+2005)."i", $_POST['season']))
        {
            $chk=" checked=\"checked\" ";
        }
    }
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"season[]\" ".$chk." value=\"".(($i+2005)."i")."\"> ".($i+2005)."i";
    }
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Edit 3: I feel like this is starting to really answer much more than one question :)

You can simply check the textbox to make sure it isn't empty and then append to a SQL string:

```
$sql="";
if(!empty($_POST['text1']))
{
    $sql.=" and ftgf>= ".$_POST['text1']." ";
}
```

Having said that, I would strongly suggest that you NEVER allow the user to enter in parts of the actual SQL you will run - unless it is a closed/secure environment, which means NOT an ope website.

Comment: It works but the problem that I now have is checking the checkboxes checked after submitting the form. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Just one other thing! If I was using words instead of numbers who would it look? As in not seasons (years) but say for example teams.

Comment: @user3581707 See edit 2. Now working with strings instead of numbers. Output is `.... and season in ('2008i', '2009i') `

Comment: Just one more! :)

I have two textboxes where you can enter a number in each which will output something like 'AND ftgf >= 2 AND ftga <= 4' where 2 would equal textbox1 and 4 would equal textbox2 is there anyway of doing a similar thing where if they are blank then the array returns nothing but if they are filled in then it returns the example above?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the below code

```
$seasons = array($season2005,$season2006,$season2007,$season2008,$season2009,$season2010,$season2011,$season2012,$season2013);
    //start
    $seasons2 = array();
    foreach ($seasons as $season)
    {
        if($season!=="0000")
        {
            array_push($seasons2,$season);
        }
    }
    $seasonpick = implode(",",$seasons2);
   //end
```